# Retrieve selected item from QListView PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

This is a question that has been asked many time on stackoverflow , and i have gone through all of them but they don't seem to solve the problem. I just want to know which item was clicked on the QListView.

Here's the code that i'm trying out .

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self,data=[],parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self,parent)
        self._data=data

    def rowCount(self,parent):
        return len(self._data)

    def data(self,index,role):

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()]


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(640, 480)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView(Form)
        self.listView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listView"))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        data=["one","two","three","four"]
        model=MyModel(data)
        self.listView.setModel(model)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listView ,     QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("listclicked()")),self.PrintIT)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def PrintIT(self,selected):
        print "Asdf"
        self.lineEdit.text(str(self.listView.selectedItem()))
import sys

class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    def execute_event(self):
        pass
    def execute_all_event(self):
        pass
    def reload_event(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried many solutions , but none of them solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `MyForm` class:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot("QModelIndex")
def on_listView_clicked(self, model_index):
    # Process here the model index.
```

you can also know the number of the row:

```
    row_number = model_index.row()
```

Also note you are working with [QListView](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistview.html) not a [QListWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html). The last have [QListWidgetItem](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidgetitem.html) objects the one your are working with, not.

Comment: You can, but when you update your ui file and use `pyuic4` again your Ui_Form class will be overwritten. So you will lose that method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't really notice this way of connecting signals and slots.

Answer (score 3):

As RaydelMiranda says, it's not suggested to write code manually in Ui_Form class, since everything you changed will be overwitten when your GUI is changed using Qt Designer.

the reason for your failure of connect, is because there is no signal `listclicked`. `QListView` has signals inherited from `QAbstractItemView`:

```
void  activated ( const QModelIndex & index )
void  clicked ( const QModelIndex & index )
void  doubleClicked ( const QModelIndex & index )
void  entered ( const QModelIndex & index )
void  pressed ( const QModelIndex & index )
void  viewportEntered ()
```

and the way to connect signals with slots should be:

```
self.listView.clicked.connect(self.PrintIT)
```

or as RaydelMiranda's answer shows. [The new style of connecting signals and slots introduced in PyQt4 v4.5 is here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listView , QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("listclicked()")),self.PrintIT)
```

by

```
self.listView.clicked.connect(self.PrintIT)
```

then in `self.PrintIT`:

```
def PrintIT(self,index):
    print "Asdf"
    self.lineEdit.setText(str(self.listView.model().itemData(index)))
```